# How can I preserve previous android intent value when I press the back or up button?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a list view in the previous intent and when I tap on that it go to the next activity. Now when I press the back button or up button it comes back to the previous activity. But when I tap the list item again it give me run time Unexpectedly app closed error. Please help me.

Comment: Post code and error log

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without code, but maybe it's because you don't finish your next activity when you press the back button

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's because of **Activity life cycle**...
When you go to the next activity then current activity is paused for you. when you press the back or up button then your previous activity resume.
That's why you have to define your code in `onResume()` method also where you got stuck. because when you come back `onResume` method is called

Answer (score 0):

You can try override onBackPressed method in your activities :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// put a breakpoint here and check your listview/activities states

//super.onBackPressed();
}
```